# Explicit expression of the solution of this equation $\ln(x)+2x+1=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to get the explicit expression of the solution of this equation $$  \ln(x)+2x+1=0.$$

I tried to solve this by the exponential trick as follow :
$$ \ln(x)= -(2x+1)  $$  $$x = e^{-2x} e^{-1} $$  $$\frac{x}{e^{-2x}} =\frac{1}{e}.$$

So, how can I get the expression for $x$ and what do we call this kind of equations ?

Comment: You need Lambert W function

Comment: Why do you expect an algebraic solution for a mixed logarithmic equation?  ("Mixed logarithmic" meaning "containing a combination of algebraic and logarithmic operations".)

Comment: It's just an abuse of language on my part. I wanted to say an expression of x that I can analyze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\ln x+2x+1&=0\\\ln x&=-2x-1\\x&=e^{-2x}\cdot e^{-1}\\xe^{2x}&=e^{-1}\\2xe^{2x}&=2e^{-1}\\2x&=W_n\left(2e^{-1}\right)\\x&=\dfrac12W_n\left(\dfrac2e\right)\end{align}$$where $W$ is the **Lambert W Function** or **Product Log Function**.